# vim-go: how to see the log of :GoTestFunc -v?

Tags: go, vim

When I use `:GoTestFunc -v` I see the log only if the test fail, I would like to see the result even if the test success.

Thanks

Comment: How about asking on the plugin's issue tracker if you don't find the answer in its documentation?

Comment: I don't know if it's related to vim or the plugin go-vim

Comment: It should be `go-vim` plugin issue tracker

Comment: Your entry point is a plugin so your first step should be the plugin's doc. If it fails, try the plugin's issue tracker. If the maintainer thinks it's a Vim bug, try the vim_use mailing list.

Comment: Currrently vim-go doesn't deal with log outputs of `:GoTest` (and `:GoBuild` etc.) very well. There are actually some issues open for this on the bug tracker already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vim-go always clears the output window if the test succeeds[1](https://github.com/cuzelac/vim-go/blob/449dc59a/autoload/go/cmd.vim#L252). You can hack your local vim script to change the behaviour, or submit a feature request in the issue tracker.

Comment: thanks, i will now go to the issue tracker of `vim-go` like suggested.